# Jenkins CDK Permission denied

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to use aws cdk synth with jenkins but i get an error saying cdk: Permission denied

Error: [cdk:permission denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6V22V.png)

I am running the aws cdk synth command directly on the jenkins pipeline script like this: [cdk synth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y6ae.png)

I have given jenkins sudo permissions but it still doesnt work. I have tried putting the command in a bash script but then i get bash permission denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added jenkins to the ubuntu group and vice versa then restarted jenkins. After this, cdk synth was working properly. I had ran these commands before but didnt restart jenkins.

```
$ usermod -a -G ubuntu jenkins
$ usermod -a -G jenkins ubuntu
```